# Move elements in ConstrainedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code that is responsible for displaying the characteristics of the device.
I put these characteristics in Column, wrapped Card, and listed everything.
I am attaching a short code example.

```
              Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Location:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        device.location,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      const Divider(
                          color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                      Text(
                        'Status:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
                          child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Row(children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    device.status.toString().substring(7),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Expanded(
                                  child: (device.status == Status.booked)
                                      ? OutlinedButton(
                                          onPressed: () async {
                                            final user = await user_api
                                                .getUser(device.userId);

                                            Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    const UserCard(),
                                                settings: RouteSettings(
                                                  arguments:
                                                      user, //TODO: check route
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                          child: const Text("User",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              )),
                                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                            fixedSize: const Size(100, 15),
                                            side: BorderSide(
                                                width: 1.0,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                Colors.yellow[600],
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Text(''),
                                ),
                              ]))),
                      const Divider(
                          color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
```

Photo how it looks
[image]

But I would like to move the "User" button in the status column to the right. Tell me how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barrier is coming from `BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250)`. To handle view in row, we can use `Row` with  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` with `Expanded` 3 children for separation, also while using padding, provide save value on both side.

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints:
        const BoxConstraints(), //remove width, you can remove ConstrainedBox  widget
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            30, 0, 30, 0), // prvide same padding
        child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox()), //handle left sepration
              const Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "device",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {},
                    child: const Text("User",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      fixedSize: const Size(100, 15),
                      side: BorderSide(
                          width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[600],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]))),
```

[image: imgage]